# Slug that isn't whole file name in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm attempting to create a route in Next.js that follows a format like:

```
localhost:3000/post-SLUG
```

By creating a file with the name:

```
/pages/post-[slug].js
```

When I navigate to an example like `localhost:3000/post-example` I get a 404. Is it possible to do this type of routing? I realize that this is probably not the best URL setup, but I'm trying to match URLs from an already deployed site as a part of a migration to Next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do it with Next.js routing system because in order to be dynamic the part of URL must match this regular expression:

```
/\/\[[^/]+?\](?=\/|$)/
```

So the route have to be `/post/[slug]/`.

The `/pages/post-[slug].js` would be accessible as a static route `http://localhost:3000/post-[slug]`.

You can utilize a [Custom Server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) to create this kind of routes.

Comment: What if I don't want to create a custom server?